# ZELDA Guardian Puzzle Part II - Shortest Path (Unsolved for new rules)

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, puzzle, constraint-programming

This question is in relation to the following previously asked question: [Twilight Zelda Guardian Puzzle : Shortest Path (UPDATE: ADDED RULES)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245680/twilight-zelda-guardian-puzzle-shortest-path-update-added-rules)

A 1-step-less solution was uncovered, but under an incomplete set of rules.

$\hspace{2.5cm}$[image]

$\hspace{2.5cm}$Initial player setup. Link's ($\mathscr{L}$) moves reflect the path choices of guardians.

The complete rule set is as follows:

> 1. If the guardians face each other and Link, the player, moves in a way to make them collide they, in effect, stay in the same position and Link keeps his move: youtube.com/watch?v=ZNnSwc0w1oE#t=4m58s
> 2. Top-guardian-Link conga allowed: youtube.com/watch?v=oUh88KsZYCc#t=3m53s – Liz Wesley 21 mins ago
> 3. The game ends if the player jumps on a square that a guardian is set to jump on at the same time: youtube.com/watch?v=ZNnSwc0w1oE#t=2m55s
> 4. Entities which would step out of the game board do not move.
> 5. All three entities step simultaneously.
> 6. The game ends if a Link-Guardian-conga forces the guardian to chest bump the other guardian (special case).

Comment: I seek to complete the rule list and find the shortest path possible to complete the [puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7CNOnqAaCw&index=14&list=PLkBK2hrDcB5ucqVzu5cMgRNqL4sBUj7op#t=9m49s).

Comment: There may be special cases I'm not considering. If you have a question in regards to the rules, etc., ask me, and I can clarify.

Comment: There are currently 4 votes to close this question as 'unclear what you're asking'. I don't understand why - I think it's perfectly clear. You might get a better reception for this on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: Well this post doesn't contain a question and doesn't make sense unless you read the linked post. I'm guessing the votes to close are due to that. If the text from the previous question is edited in, I think all objections would disappear.